# how to remove shadow of toolbar, so it doesn't look like overlap

Tags: android, android-toolbar

[the toolbar is overlappig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80im9.jpg)

my code for toolbar and actionbar:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"


        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

if i add app:elevation="0dp" on appbar the menu will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<View xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/statusBarHeight"
    android:background="@color/accueil_colorDark"
    android:elevation="@dimen/statusBarElevation"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:popupTheme="@style/AppThemeAccueilToolbar"
    android:theme="@style/AppThemeAccueilToolbar"
    android:id="@+id/toolbarAccueil"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    materialdesign:elevation="0dp"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:outlineProvider="background"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/appBarTopMargin" >

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```